# CodeBlocks 17.12 Debug Error

Tags: c++, c, debugging, codeblocks

I am using Code Blocks 17.12 for C/C++ Programs. Debug option works for the very first time but when I reopen Code Blocks and try to debug that same program then the Debug option deactivates. At this point I have to copy code and paste it into a new project to use the Debugging again

Can anybody please help how to continue debugging on the same project without starting a new project each time after first usage?

Comment: in your question you need to include code for replicating the issue

Comment: can you please explain further?
i am unable to get what you are trying to explain me...

Comment: You might already running your program. Terminate all running instances then debug button will be enabled. Let me know it it helps. I will make it an answer.

Comment: Also you have to actually open your project (not just .cpp file) for the button to be active.